# Remove next single double quote after two double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a corrupt JSON file which I would like to fix.

I need to remove (or unescape) a single double quote after two double quotes.

Before:

```
{"name": ""Open In" button for Internet Explorer",
```

After:

```
{"name": ""Open In button for Internet Explorer",
```

Afterwards I can simply remove the two double quotes:

```
sed 's/""/"/g'
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking: Do you want to remove all double quotes in a string after the first occurance of a double-double-quote (i.e. `""`)?

Comment: More likely you want to _escape_ the inner quotes: `{"name": "\"Open In\" button for Internet Explorer",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(""[^"]*)"/\1/' input_file
{"name": ""Open In button for Internet Explorer",
```